# Find the degenerate basic feasible solutions

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, operations-research

Find the degenerate basic feasible solutions for the polyhedron
$$x_1 + 4x_2 ≤ 8 ;$$
$$x_1 + 2x_2 ≤ 4 ;$$
$$x_1, x_2 ≥ 0.$$

Does degeneracy depend on the representation of the polyhedron?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried plotting your constraints and finding the solution(s) that have more active constraints than the number of variables? Since your problem is 2-dimensional this would be an easy way to find solutions you then can check.

As for your second question, yes! Degeneracy of a basic feasible solution does depend on the representation of the polyhedron. One example given in a Linear Optimization book by Dimitris Bertsimas is the following Polyhedron:
$$
P=\{x \in \mathbb{R^3}: x_1-x_2 = 0, x_1+x_2+2x_3 = 2, \text{and } x_1,x_2,x_3 \geq 0 \}
=\{x \in \mathbb{R^3}: x_1-x_2 = 0, x_1+x_2+2x_3 = 2, \text{and } x_1,x_3 \geq 0 \}.
$$
The constraint $x_1-x_2=0$ gives us the possibility to remove the non-negativity constraint for $x_2$ in the first representation. 
For the first representation, the solution (0,0,1) is degenerate, but in the second representation it is not.

Comment: how to check  "more active constraints than the number of variables "? Does it mean the intersection of more than two lines in 2-D?I am sorry if I am asking easy questions.

Comment: No problem @AbhishekKumar. A constraint is active in a solution when the solution resides on the line representing the constraint. So yes, you are right. You need to find the point that is in the intersection of more than two lines representing your polyhedra in 2 dimensions. Remember to count your non-negative constraints.

Comment: can you look at this question also-  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3533082/find-all-degenerate-basic-feasible-solution-of-the-system